# How do I stop my css from overlapping in django?

Tags: html, css, django

So while rendering I'm having problem as my two of my elements are overlapping.

Image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyOF2.jpg

here's the relevant code :

```
    <style type="text/css">
    .box{
        position: absolute;
        left: 50px;
        width: calc(80% - 100px);
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<h1>Post Title</h1>
<small> by dell | Posted on Nov. 7, 2020, 9:40 p.m. </small>

<br/>
<div class="box">
<p> <p>Sample Post Body</p></p>
</div>
<br/>


    <form method="POST">
        <div class="form-group">

        <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="zlYmcOuhui0Tv0n3vtQ8gM7AE6cvbXbZSyXwudTzEN8M30RoYNzfgHGmaKx5IhiM"><p><label for="id_body">Body:
</label> <textarea name="body" cols="40" rows="10" required id="id_body">
</textarea></p>

        <button class="btn btn-secondary"> submit comment </button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

I just can't seem to figure out how do I make the Post body and the Form element separate.

Comment: Enclose your box and form in  different div and add < br> between them

Comment: I tried It. It doesn't work, it still renders the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Question as firstly nothing to do with django it's happening because position of box is absolute either remove the `position: absolute;` or have the form and and box class whatever its is div or or button separately in different div's and add `<br>` between them

Answer (score 0):

This worked  I have added div around your form and box and separated by < br> also I remove position:absolute

```
<style type="text/css">
.box{

    left: 50px;
    width: calc(80% - 100px);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<h1>Post Title</h1>
<small> by dell | Posted on Nov. 7,
2020, 9:40 p.m. </small>
<br><br>
<div>
<div class="box">
<p> <p>Sample Post Body</p></p>
</div>
<br/>
</div>
<br>
<div>
<form method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">

    <input type="hidden"
name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="zlYmcOuhui0Tv0n3vtQ8gM7AE6cvbXbZSyXwudTzEN8M30RoYNzfgHGmaKx5IhiM"><p><label for="id_body">Body:
</label> <textarea name="body"
cols="40" rows="10" required
id="id_body"</textarea></p>
<button class="btn btn-secondary">
submit comment </button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, two items must be relative to one another or put into a table to separate their positions. In your case, you have a `position: absolute;` that is interfering with the `position: auto;`. In this case, you have a few options:

1. `body { position:relative !important;display:block; }`. This is for simple applications where each element needs to be separated for individuality. The `!important` property classifies your specification in markup as the 'leading' one.
2. `<br />` between each HTML element. This will add a line-break to the element so that they are separated relatively on your page.
3. Put a `position: relative;` on each individual element. Only use `position: absolute;` when you need to add some sort of footer or header or shape to your `div` or other item. Absolute positioning doesn't change in response to the page width, so this is a big markup issue.

Hopefully this helped.

**Additional Resources:**

[1] https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ -- A guide to flexbox for forms and other web design markup. It is a trending setup for positioning that not many people take advantage of.

[2] https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display -- Learn how to separate elements with block, inline, flex, inline-block, or none.

*Note: This bug has nothing to do with Django.*